# Storing date and time of INSERT in MySQL

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Time & Date Stamp in a MySQL table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642410/time-date-stamp-in-a-mysql-table-row)

What would be the best way to store a date and time that the INSERT statement was run? Would it be to include the Now() function in the query? Once that is done, will it be possible to calculate if 72 hours has passed?

Comment: do you want to know the data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `TimeStamp` field, and in particular you can create the table itself to do all the work for you:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `updatetime` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Here, when the record is created (I.e. INSERT) the database will populate the field contents for you.

You can run a simple query using `DATE_DIFF()` or `TIME_DIFF` function to check for any records that are greater than 72 hours. Note, you may want to use the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function here too.

For more info have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174058/mysql-timediff-to-hours).

Comment: Okay thank you. What would I need to do to check if 72 hours has passed since that time?

Comment: You can run a simple query using DATE_DIFF() or UNIX_TIMESTAMP() but the performance will suck.

Comment: @symcbean is right, have a look at his comparison method

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify an explicit value if you define datetime attribute with a default value for the column of [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp). If define the type as [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html), then it will be updated to the current time each time the record is modified unless you specifically override the behaviour.

> will it be possible to calculate if 72 hours has passed?

Yes - but make sure you put all the static calculations on one side of the comparison operation:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE NOW() - INTERVAL 72 HOURS > yourtable.created_time;
```

Will be faster than....

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE NOW()> yourtable.created_time + INTERVAL 72 HOURS;
```

Even without an index on the created time. If you do have an index on the created time, then the first query won't use it, but the 2nd query will go a lot faster.